# Jest mock callback function from a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a function inside my component which is only called when the API request is successful. For context when you click a button I call this function:

```
return onUpdate(params, setError, success, cancel);
```

and when it is successful it calls the success function:

```
const success = (data) => {
  // do some stuff when successful
};
```

The `onUpdate` function is imported and is the API request which looks like this:

```
const onUpdate = (params, onError, onSuccess, onCancel) => {
  save(params)
    .then((data) => {
      if (onSuccess) {
        onSuccess(data.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        if (onCancel) {
          onCancel();
        }
      } else {
        onError(error);
      }
    });
};
```

I have been mocking the implementation of this function in my tests like so:

```
jest.mock('../../dataAccess', () => ({
  onUpdate: jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementation(
      (params, onError, onSuccess) =>
        new Promise((resolve) => resolve(onSuccess(response))),
    ),
}));
```

From reading the docs / stack overflow it looks like a callback is passed in [an example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099600/mock-function-with-jest-that-contains-a-callback-as-an-argument-which-returns-a) and if I add the other params and add `cb` as the last param it still doesn't seem to fire my success function.

What do I need to mock to get my test to call my success function in my component? I am sure it is something very small but not quite sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a `new Promise` its basically covert you function from callback based to async function, try to do something similar to:

```js
jest.mock('../../dataAccess', () => ({
  onUpdate: jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementation(
      (params, onError, onSuccess) => {
        onSuccess(response)
      }
    ),
}));
```

Or even easier:

```js
jest.mock('../../dataAccess', () => ({
  onUpdate: (params, onError, onSuccess) => {
     onSuccess(response)
  }
}));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried the first option which would help with my other tests but the success function never gets called. I am happy to change to the second easier option if I could solve the error I get with when checking if my update function is called: ```Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function onUpdate]```

This is the line in the test: ```expect(onUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();```

Comment: @saunders
In the test, you can create a function, you can validate that onUpdate called in different ways, Example 1: create a dummy function `jest.fn()` and pass it as param to onUpdate, onUpdate -> will call you dummy func and can validate that with `toHaveBeenCalled`